# Private video via REST api

Tags: angularjs, html, rest, video, api-design

Hi I'm trying to implement auth protected audio/video stream in angular app via REST api. The goal is to secure audio/video to not to be shared with other not logged users. I tried single use token so flow looks like this:

- Angular ask for single use token after you click play button `POST: file/1/token`
- Angular get the token and paste token into url `?token=...`
- Stream request is send to the server `GET: file/1?token=...`
- Server checks the token and removes it from database
- If token is right stream begin

The problem came when you click on timeline where stream is not buffered yet so the browser automatically sends another request which of course is unauthorized because token has been already removed.

I want to keep api stateless but as you see some kind of state is forced by html media.

I would love to hear your hints or solutions on that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved for now. Maybe it's not the best solution but it covers all requirements.
We decided to use session which breaks the REST principles but simply works.

Now we getting token as it was before `POST: file/1/token`

Getting file with provided token `GET: file/1?token=...`

The difference is that in the controller we open new PHP session, save token into session and remove it from database. Now we are able to check whether token is in database or in the session.

So if you send link to other people they don't have an access. Only you have access as long as token is in the PHP session.